# How to apply matrices to dnd style games

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

While playing a game, I needed to match 5 Characters to 5 Classes to optimise my team. I've listed the classes each character is suited for: Mage-2,4 Ninja-1,2 Thief-3,5 Warrior-1,2,4 Cleric-2,3,5. I'm vaguely guessing that matrices could be used to solve this.

My idea is (just a wild guess) if we assign values 1-5 for the characters too and create simultaneous equations with unknowns a-e representing the possible classes a character can take, i.e: a+2b+3c+4d+5e=k, we could create large matrices; solving would likely yield the best class matches for each character.

So,

1. Anyone has an idea on how to solve this with maths?
2. Could my idea work? Or is there some tweaking needed to my model?

Comment: It sounds like you have a bipartite graph for which you need a [perfect matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comment, what you are looking for is a [perfect matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) (or more generally, optimal perhaps) in a bipartite graph. There are several approaches that one can take to solving this problem; one of these is implemented in the Python "Network X" as the [max_weight_matching](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html#networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching) method. Here is a script implementing this.

```
import networkx as nx

adj_dic = {
    'M':[2,4],
    'N':[1,2],
    'T':[3,5],
    'W':[1,2,4],
    'C':[2,3,5]
}

# generate graph from above data
G = nx.Graph()
for k,v in adj_dic.items():
    for n in v:
        G.add_edge(k,n)

# compute perfect matching (if one exists)
match = nx.max_weight_matching(G)

# generate visualization
import networkx as nx

left = 'MNTWC'
right = range(1,6)
pos = {}
for i,l,r in zip(range(5),left,right):
    pos[l] = (0,-i)
    pos[r] = (1,-i)
colors = ['red' if edge in match or edge[::-1] in match else 'black' for edge in G.edges()]
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True, node_color = 'orange', edge_color = colors, pos = pos)
```

The resulting visualization:

[image]

In other words, one solution is to pair classes to players as

1: warrior, 2: ninja, 3: cleric, 4: mage, 5: thief.